# How to replace all the border value of matrix with my list clockwise in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

How to replace the border of M matrix with the given list clockwise?

This is my Input matrix -M

```
3 3
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

(Here 3-rows 3- columns)

and this is my list to replace all the border values of M.
['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18']

Output need to got:

```
11 12 13 
18  5 14 
17 16 15
```

My code:

```
r,c=map(int,input().split())
m=[list(map(str,input().split())) for i in range(r)]
print(m)
l=['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18']

for i in range(0,len(m)):
  for j in range(0,len(m[i])):
    for x in range(len(l)):
      if m[i][j]!=m[i][0] and m[i][j]!=m[i][-1]:
        m[i][j]=l[x]

for i in range(r):
  for j in range(c):
    print(m[i][j],end=" ")
  print()
```

output got by me:

```
1 18 3 
4 18 6 
7 18 9
```

I seriously confused how to change all the border values with the given list ....If you know how to do please guide me

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how about flatten the matrix, replace items, then build back to matrix?

Comment: yeah its good, but how can I find the border index correctly and change accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the indexes of borders of matrix and then replace them with the given array, the pattern is like this:

```
top_border=[(0,0),(0,1)...(0,n-1)]
right_border=[(1,n-1), ...,(n-1,n-1)]
bottom_border=[(n-1,n-2) ... (n-1,0)]
left_border=[(n-2, 0) ... (1, 0)]
```

This pattern can be achieved by four loop. after producing this pattern you can replace matrix by indexes that generated

```python
# top_border=[(0,0),(0,1)...(0,n-1)], right_border=[(1,n-1), ...,(n-1,n-1)], bottom_border=[(n-1,n-2) ... (n-1,0)], left_border=[(n-2, 0) ... (1, 0)]

from operator import le


def indexes(n):
    idxs = []
    for i in range(n):
        idxs.append((0,i))
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        idxs.append((i,n-1))
    for i in range(n-1, -1,-1):
        idxs.append((n-1,i))
    for i in range(n-2,0,-1):
        idxs.append((i,0))
    return idxs

def printer(m):
    for l in m:
        print(l)

def new_matrix(n):
    s = 0
    m = []
    for _ in range(n):
        t = []
        for _ in range(n):
            t.append(s)
            s += 1
        m.append(t)
    return m

def swap_borders(m, idxs):
    for i, idx in enumerate(idxs):
        m[idx[0]][idx[1]] = l[i]
    return m

n = 4
new_label = lambda n: [i for i in range(11,11+(4*n-4))]

m = new_matrix(n)
l = new_label(n)
idxs = indexes(n)

printer(m)

m = swap_borders(m, idxs)

print(">"*10)
printer(m)
```

The output will be

```python
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
>>>>>>>>>>
[11, 12, 13, 14]
[22, 5, 6, 15]
[21, 9, 10, 16]
[20, 19, 18, 17]
```

By this method for matrix(n*n) you have O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Hey @S4eed3sm very thank you I understood now now how to access the border of matrix thank you

Comment: hi bro  @S4eed3sm While working with 4X4 matrices it is not working why?

Comment: It's works for 4*4, I thinks you can't create l correctly. use this version